# Selecting text between parenthesis in Emacs+AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am looking for a way to select text inside surrounding nearest parenthesis. For example if I am working with a string

```
(text \textit{text2 $a^2=b$} text3)
```

this command selects whole string in case if my cursor is on `text`, `textit` or `text3`. In case my cursor is on `tex2` it selects

```
{text2 $a^2=b$}
```

An if it is inside '$..$' it selects math expression. It would be very nice if i could interactively change the selection region from smaller to bigger and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the cursor to the opening bracket and then press C-M-SPC. Here's a similar question (with answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194417/how-to-mark-the-text-between-the-parentheses-in-emacs

There's also Emacswiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NavigatingParentheses